# Prevent input until first action finishes?

Tags: jquery

In my code I have a div that moves left and right when buttons are pressed. However, when I press the button multiple times it moves respective to the number of presses. What I want it to do is prevent any input to be given ( or the button to be pressed ) until after the animation has finished.

I tried using a delay to keep the actions from 'queuing' but that simply put them off by a few seconds.

Here is my code* currently as well as a jsfiddle example of the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjfuv/ (Yes they are different, the example is not made by myself)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var clickState = 0;
var cssForState = [{
        'margin-left': '0px'
    },{
        'margin-left': '-850px'
    },{
        'margin-left': '-1700px'
    }];

var advanceToNextClickState = function() {
    clickState++;
    if (clickState >= cssForState.length)
        clickState = 0;
};

var previousClickState = function() {
    clickState--;
    if (clickState < 0)
        clickState= 2;

};
$('.RButton').click(function (e) {
    console.log("Received click while clickState = " + clickState);
    advanceToNextClickState();
    $('.slideContain').delay(150).animate(cssForState[clickState]);
});    

$('.LButton').click(function (e) {
    console.log("Received click while clickState = " + clickState);
    previousClickState();
    $('.slideContain').delay(150).animate(cssForState[clickState]);
});    
});
```

*S/O to the user who helped me on my last question too, I like the way this works ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.RButton').click(function (e) {
    console.log("Received click while clickState = " + clickState);

    //makes your button unclickable
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.attr("disabled", true);

    advanceToNextClickState();
    $('.slideContain').delay(150).animate(cssForState[clickState], function(){
        //when animation is over, make it clickable
        $btn.attr("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bind and unbind method to add your function . before animation unbind this and after animation again bind it .

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code inside your left and right button click functions with a boolean variable.

pass a function into the delay function, so that when the animation is over

you turn the boolean value back to false.